# Electron App with Vue and vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder can't working with Tesseract.js

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder, tesseract.js, asar

I have created a project with vue-service-cli. After trying to use tesseract OCR but I can't load lang.traineddata locally and remotely. I have tried examples (they work) from tesseract.js repo and other many ways but with no result. When I try to load them I see standard error:

```
    Error opening data file ./eng.traineddata
    Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
    Failed loading language 'eng'
    Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
    AdaptedTemplates != nullptr:Error:Assert failed:in file /src/src/classify/adaptmatch.cpp, line 196
    trap!
```

I suspect this is a problem by .asar archive format ( from [vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder) ), which is in "/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar". I can load files from ./public but I was read languages files have to are in the process directory - I don't know if it's true. Some configuration can't work together.

My code

```js
    const data = await Tesseract.recognize(
    "https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png",
    "eng",
    {
      logger: console.log,
      corePath: window.location.origin + "/tesseract/tesseract-core.wasm.js",
      workerPath: window.location.origin + "/tesseract/worker.min.js",
      langPath: window.location.origin + "/tesseract/tessdata"
      //or
      langPath: path.join(__dirname, "tessdata")
    }
```

My dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.4.4",
    "electron": "5.0.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "tesseract.js": "2.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.0.2",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.3.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "pug": "^2.0.4",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "^1.4.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
```

EDIT:
I noticed that https://github.com/auth0-blog/electron-vue project working fine with Tesseract.js. That project uses Vue but without vue-vli-service which means it doesn't have vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder which confirms the above thesis. I'm still looking for a solution with the use vue-cli

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution thanks to the module owner.
[github issue](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/issues/652)